# ASP .NET core Razor page - Avoid refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have tow buttons in one Form, first button for add website info to a local table and second button for add social media info to another table, after all info added locally,
then I can click on 'add all info' button for add all info in same time to database.

My question is how can I add info to a table without refreshing the page?

AddAllInfo.cshtml:

````
 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" asp-for="NewWebSiteInfo.websiteName">Website URL</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="NewWebSiteInfo.websiteName" class="form-control" />
</div>

 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" asp-for="NewWebSiteInfo.websiteUrl">Website URL</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="NewWebSiteInfo.websiteUrl" class="form-control" />
</div>

<button type="submit" validatedisable="True" asp-page-handler="AddWebsiteInfo" class="btn btn-primary" >Add Website info</button>

 <div class="mb-3">
                @if (AddInfoModel.WebSitelist.Count > 0)
                {
                    <div class="col-12 border p-3">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead style="background-color:lightgray">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>WebsiteName</th>
                                    <th>websiteURL</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (Website item in AddAllInfoModel.WebSitelist)
                                {
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>@item.WebsiteName</td>
                                        <td>@item.websiteURL</td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                }

</div>

</br>
</br>

 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" asp-for="NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaName">Social Media</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaName" class="form-control" />
</div>

 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" asp-for="NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaAccount">Account</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaAccount" class="form-control" />
</div>

<button type="submit" validatedisable="True" asp-page-handler="AddSocialMediaInfo" class="btn btn-primary" >Add socil Media info</button>

<div class="mb-3">
                @if (AddInfoModel.SocialMedialist.Count > 0)
                {
                    <div class="col-12 border p-3">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead style="background-color:lightgray">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>SocialMediaName</th>
                                    <th>SocialMediaAccount</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (SocialMedia item in AddAllInfoModel.SocialMedialist)
                                {
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>@item.SocialMediaName</td>
                                        <td>@item.SocialMediaAccount</td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                }

</div>
</br>
 <div class="col-4 offset-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"> Add all info </button>
 </div>

</form> ```
                                 
AddAllInfo.cshtml.cs:
                                        
    public void OnPostAddSocialMediaInfo()
{
    SocialMedialist.Add(new SocialMedia { SocialMediaName = NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaName, 
    SocialMediaAccount=NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaAccount});
}

public void OnPostAddWebsiteInfo()
{
    WebSitelist.Add(new WebSite { WebSiteName = NewWebSiteInfo.WebsiteName, 
      websiteUrl =NewWebSiteInfo.websiteUrl});
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use js to pass data to handler,and then use js to add html to tbody,here is a demo to add data to table without refresh the page:

````
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" asp-for="NewWebSiteInfo.websiteName">Website URL</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="NewWebSiteInfo.websiteName" class="form-control" />
</div>

 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" asp-for="NewWebSiteInfo.websiteUrl">Website URL</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="NewWebSiteInfo.websiteUrl" class="form-control" />
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="AddWebsiteInfo()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Website info">
 <div class="mb-3">
                @if (AddInfoModel.WebSitelist.Count > 0)
                {
                    <div class="col-12 border p-3">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead style="background-color:lightgray">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>WebsiteName</th>
                                    <th>websiteURL</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (Website item in AddAllInfoModel.WebSitelist)
                                {
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>@item.WebsiteName</td>
                                        <td>@item.websiteURL</td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                }

</div>

</br>
</br>

 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" asp-for="NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaName">Social Media</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaName" class="form-control" />
</div>

 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" asp-for="NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaAccount">Account</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaAccount" class="form-control" />
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="AddSocialMediaInfo()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add socil Media info">

<div class="mb-3">
                @if (AddInfoModel.SocialMedialist.Count > 0)
                {
                    <div class="col-12 border p-3">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead style="background-color:lightgray">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>SocialMediaName</th>
                                    <th>SocialMediaAccount</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (SocialMedia item in AddAllInfoModel.SocialMedialist)
                                {
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>@item.SocialMediaName</td>
                                        <td>@item.SocialMediaAccount</td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                }

</div>
</br>
 <div class="col-4 offset-2">
     <input type="button" onclick="AddAllInfo()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add all info">
 </div>

</form> ```
````

js:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function AddWebsiteInfo() {
            var NewWebSiteInfo = {
                'websiteName': $("#NewWebSiteInfo_websiteName").val(),
                'websiteUrl': $("#NewWebSiteInfo_websiteUrl").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '?handler=AddWebsiteInfo',
                data: NewWebSiteInfo,
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var html = "<tr><td>" + data.websiteName + "</td><td>" + data.websiteUrl + "</td></tr>";
                    $("tbody")[0].innerHTML = $("tbody")[0].innerHTML + html;
                }
            });
        }
        function AddSocialMediaInfo() {
            var NewAddSocialMediaInfo = {
                'SocialMediaName': $("#NewSocialMediaInfo_SocialMediaName").val(),
                'SocialMediaAccount': $("#NewSocialMediaInfo_SocialMediaAccount").val()
                
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '?handler=AddSocialMediaInfo',
                data: NewAddSocialMediaInfo,
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var html = "<tr><td>" + data.socialMediaName + "</td><td>" + data.socialMediaAccount + "</td></tr>";
                    $("tbody")[1].innerHTML = $("tbody")[1].innerHTML + html;
                }
            });
        }
        function AddAllInfo() {
            AddWebsiteInfo();
            AddSocialMediaInfo();
        }
    </script>
}
```

handler:

```
[BindProperty]
        public WebSiteInfo NewWebSiteInfo { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public SocialMediaInfo NewSocialMediaInfo { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
        public JsonResult OnPostAddWebsiteInfo()
        {
            WebSitelist.Add(new WebSite { WebSiteName = NewWebSiteInfo.WebsiteName, 
            websiteUrl =NewWebSiteInfo.websiteUrl});
            return new JsonResult(NewWebSiteInfo);
        }
        public JsonResult OnPostAddSocialMediaInfo()
        {
            SocialMedialist.Add(new SocialMedia { SocialMediaName = NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaName, 
            SocialMediaAccount=NewSocialMediaInfo.SocialMediaAccount});
            return new JsonResult(NewSocialMediaInfo);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to run the post request in javascript, this will not refresh the page.

2nd option is by calling the get method again at the end of the post method and then passing the model with the data to the get. So that when the page refreshes the data is filled in again